# Generic method with having to specify TResult

Tags: c#, generics

I have to following method

```
public DataSetConfiguration<T> PropertyMap<TEntity, TResult>( Expression<Func<TEntity, TResult>> property, Func<DataRow, TResult> mapping )
```

I was wondering if anyone knows a way so that user does not have to specify TResult and only TEntity or is this not possible thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `dynamic` keyword, read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx).

The problem is though, that it does not give the full Intellisense, and compilation time checking of your code, which may make thing more difficult to analyze.

```
public DataSetConfiguration<T> PropertyMap<TEntity>( Expression<Func<TEntity, dynamic>> property, Func<DataRow, dynamic> mapping )
```

Also `T` is not specified in your code. Not clear what to do with it.

Comment: Yeah i thought of dynamic but I want to keep the full intellisense

Comment: Then the answer is no, or depend on an `interface` if possible.

Comment: Personally, I'd rather type the full thing than use the `dynamic` keyword and lose all compiler support. `dynamic` is for *dynamic* types, not for lazy developers.

Comment: @Lukazoid: I totally agree.

Answer (score 2):

When using your `PropertyMap` method, you may specify the type of the parameter of your `Expression<Func<TEntity, TResult>>`, this will mean you do not need to specify the generic types, i.e.

```
PropertyMap((SomeEntity e) => e.SomeProperty, dr => dr.Field<int>("SomeKey"));
```

However, this does still require you to return the correct type of result when reading from the `DataRow`, hence the use of `dr.Field<int>` (The example assumes the property is an int).